# Android: Google scheduler example does not work

Tags: android

I download the example from [here](http://developer.android.com/training/scheduling/alarms.html). I imported the project in eclipse, added support library v4 to build path. When I run the app, it always crashes. This is the error in LogCat: Could anyone please help me? Thanks.

```
05-08 22:39:41.396: E/dalvikvm(22444): Could not find class 'com.example.android.scheduler.SampleAlarmReceiver', referenced from method com.example.android.scheduler.MainActivity.<init>
05-08 22:39:41.406: E/AndroidRuntime(22444): FATAL EXCEPTION: main
05-08 22:39:41.406: E/AndroidRuntime(22444): java.lang.NoClassDefFoundError: com.example.android.scheduler.SampleAlarmReceiver
05-08 22:39:41.406: E/AndroidRuntime(22444):    at com.example.android.scheduler.MainActivity.<init>(MainActivity.java:34)
05-08 22:39:41.406: E/AndroidRuntime(22444):    at java.lang.Class.newInstanceImpl(Native Method)
05-08 22:39:41.406: E/AndroidRuntime(22444):    at java.lang.Class.newInstance(Class.java:1319)
05-08 22:39:41.406: E/AndroidRuntime(22444):    at android.app.Instrumentation.newActivity(Instrumentation.java:1071)
05-08 22:39:41.406: E/AndroidRuntime(22444):    at android.app.ActivityThread.performLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:2369)
05-08 22:39:41.406: E/AndroidRuntime(22444):    at android.app.ActivityThread.handleLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:2521)
05-08 22:39:41.406: E/AndroidRuntime(22444):    at android.app.ActivityThread.access$600(ActivityThread.java:162)
05-08 22:39:41.406: E/AndroidRuntime(22444):    at android.app.ActivityThread$H.handleMessage(ActivityThread.java:1370)
05-08 22:39:41.406: E/AndroidRuntime(22444):    at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:99)
05-08 22:39:41.406: E/AndroidRuntime(22444):    at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:158)
05-08 22:39:41.406: E/AndroidRuntime(22444):    at android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:5777)
05-08 22:39:41.406: E/AndroidRuntime(22444):    at java.lang.reflect.Method.invokeNative(Native Method)
05-08 22:39:41.406: E/AndroidRuntime(22444):    at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:511)
05-08 22:39:41.406: E/AndroidRuntime(22444):    at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(ZygoteInit.java:1083)
05-08 22:39:41.406: E/AndroidRuntime(22444):    at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:850)
05-08 22:39:41.406: E/AndroidRuntime(22444):    at dalvik.system.NativeStart.main(Native Method)
```

Comment: Did you solve this issue?

Answer (score 1):

I got the same issue when I added [support v4 lib](http://developer.android.com/tools/support-library/features.html#v4) via "add external jar" in build path.

To solve it:

- remove the support v4 lib from build path
- create a directory named "libs" in the root on the project
- copy the lib into the newly created directory.

Eclipse should now show a new "library directory" in your project called "Android Private Libraries" which include support library v4

Refresh, clean ... and it should work.